# TITANIUM how to get the listview's value?

Tags: javascript, android, listview, titanium

I hope to get the listview children text, I can't found the way to get it.
 my listview build code:

```
var myTemplate = {
    childTemplates: [
            {                            // Title 
            type: 'Ti.UI.Label',     // Use a label for the title 
            bindId: 'info',          // Maps to a custom info property of the item data
            properties: {            // Sets the label properties
                color: 'black',
                font: { fontFamily:'Arial', fontSize: '20dp', fontWeight:'bold' },
                left: 0, top: 0,
            }
        },
        {                            // Subtitle
            type: 'Ti.UI.Label',     // Use a label for the subtitle
            bindId: 'es_info',       // Maps to a custom es_info property of the item data
            properties: {            // Sets the label properties
                color: 'black',
                font: { fontFamily:'Arial', fontSize: '20dp' },
                right: 0, top: '0dp',
                accessoryType: Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE
            }
        }
    ]
};

var table = Ti.UI.createListView({
// Maps myTemplate dictionary to 'template' string
    templates: { 'template': myTemplate },
    bottom:'50dp',
    editing : true,
    defaultItemTemplate: 'template'
});
var sections = [];


ProcuctRS = db.execute('select uniqnumber,barcode,scantimes,quantity from product where batchno=?',Titanium.App.Properties.getString("batchnumber"));
while (ProcuctRS.isValidRow())  
    {  
        var BNO = ProcuctRS.fieldByName('barcode');  
        var SCTIME = ProcuctRS.fieldByName('scantimes');  
        var QUANTITY = ProcuctRS.fieldByName('quantity'); 

        var PDSection = Ti.UI.createListSection({ headerTitle: BNO});
        var PDDataSet = [
                            { es_info: {text: 'Scan times :' + SCTIME}, info: {text: 'Quantity :'+ QUANTITY}},
                        ];
        PDSection.setItems(PDDataSet);
        sections.push(PDSection);
        ProcuctRS.next(); 
    }  
ProcuctRS.close();
table.sections = sections;
self.add(table);
```

now I want to change the info and es_info text, I tried different meth,
for example:

```
    table.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e){
            var item = e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
            e.section.es_info.color = 'orange';
            e.section.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item); 
};
```

but it doesn't work. 
what can i do ?help! thank you

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is relevant (or just copy-paste mistake) but you missed ')' at the end of your event listener

```
 table.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e){
        var item = e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
        e.section.es_info.color = 'orange';
        e.section.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try editing: false

```
    var table = Ti.UI.createListView({
        // Maps myTemplate dictionary to 'template' string
        templates: { 'template': myTemplate },
        bottom:'50dp',
        editing : false,
        defaultItemTemplate: 'template'
    });
```